# How to align divs to separate directions?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put choice of country to the right side of navigation but for some reason I am unable to do so. Float does not work, any suggestions why or what else use? I put different divs child so I can control them but there seems to be something blocking it.

[image: screenshot]

```css
.navMain {
  background: #87CEEB;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.nav1 div {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.active {
  background-color: #133C55;
}

.active a {
  color: #87CEEB;
}

.dropdown div {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.dropbtn {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #87CEEB;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 4rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  height: 3.5rem;
  background: #84D2F6;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3046E8F;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navMain">
    <div class="nav1">
      <div class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Guide</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">About</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><img src="img/united-kingdom.png" alt="" width=45px;></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content bxs">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/united-states.png" alt="" width=45px;></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Switch `.nav1` and `.dropdown` in your html and give `float: right` to your `.dropdown`.

Comment: @Jack Sylvane, you just accept the answer of the guy who just copy mine ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove display: inline-flex; from .navMain then try to apply float. Flex supports newspaper like structure that why your float is not working

Comment: @kaldoran, i didn't stole your answer, i just edit and scroll up and see your answer. I feel sorry if you think like that.

Comment: @hameedanaz: it looks *exactly* like you stole kaldoran's answer. In future, when updating your answer to include other people's ideas, please credit them for it; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.

Comment: @Matt, if you believe like that, then please mark kaldoran's answer as answer and remove mine, i dont want the lable of "stole" b/c  didn't. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `display:block;` to `.navMain` and `float:right;` to your language switch.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/mtd06tcs/

Hint: change the navigation items to list items.

Best and good luck,
C

Answer (score 0):

Since .navMain is an `inline-flex`, just add an `justify-content: space-between;` to .navMain

https://jsfiddle.net/tg4xup7b/

```css
.navMain {
  background: #87CEEB;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav1 div { 
  width: 10rem;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.active {background-color: #133C55;}
.active  a {color: #87CEEB;}

.dropdown div {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.dropbtn {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #87CEEB;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 4rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  height: 3.5rem;
  background: #84D2F6;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.2rem ;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3046E8F;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navMain">
    <div class="nav1">
      <div class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Guide</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">About</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><img src="img/united-kingdom.png" alt="" width=45px;></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content bxs">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/united-states.png" alt="" width=45px;></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```